# LOad JS script, when user press the back button on browser

Tags: javascript

I have a js script code and I want to use only, when user press the back button on browser (load js script on the new page).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the browser buttons to trigger any event on the page, so what you're trying to do doesn't seem to be possible.